# Checking for in-app purchases

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

Following instructions from: https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html under Query Purchased Items, I am checking for purchased items.

My code looks like this:

```
    private void lookForPurchases() {
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener lookForPurchasesListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error checking for purchases:" + result.toString());
            }
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Processing purchases." + inventory.toString());
                if(inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_LEXCOINS_100)){
                    Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_LEXCOINS_100);
                    consumeCoinPurchase(purchase);
                }
                if(inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_LEXCOINS_550)){
                    Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_LEXCOINS_550);
                    consumeCoinPurchase(purchase);
                }
                if(inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_LEXCOINS_1200)){
                    Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_LEXCOINS_1200);
                    consumeCoinPurchase(purchase);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Log.i(TAG, "Looking for purchases");
    if(inAppBillingHelper == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Null preventing query inventory");
    } else {
        try {
            inAppBillingHelper.queryInventoryAsync(lookForPurchasesListener);
        } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error retrieving purchases.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

In the log, though, the last thing I get is "Looking for purchases" with nothing following. It looks like I should get something on any branch, so, does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

No errors or anything, it just never seems to come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the line `handler.post` deep in IabHelper (Google Code) where it was executing my callback I was passing in. The handler.post was getting called, buy my callback never was. I'm not sure how that happened.

I replaced the handler.post with a AsyncTask and posted the call of my callback in the `onPostExecute` method to get it run on the UI thread. This appears to have solved my problem.